# Determine place values for any base

Tags: math

I'm looking for a function that will determine the value of a place given a number and a base.  For example,

**Given:**

> ```
> Whole Value: 1120
> Base: 10
> Place: Tens place
> ```

**Should return:** 2

Does anybody know the math for this?

Edit: The function is also expected to pass the whole value numerically, not as a string like "e328fa" or something.  Also the return value should be numeric as well, so a FindInPlace(60 (whole value), 16 (base), 2 (place, 1-based index)) should return 3.

Comment: How are you going to input the place into the function?  For example, if I want the first digit in 0x3AF, can I call get_value_of_place(0x3AF, 16, 256)?

Comment: Place could be specified in one of two ways.  In the example I gave, you could either pass it in as 2 (second place) or just simply 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1-based place indexing the formula is:

placeval = floor(number / (base^(place-1))) mod base

In Python:

```
def FindInPlace(number, base, place):
    return number//base**(place-1) % base
```

Comment: Perfect.  What does the double slash do?

Comment: The double slash is "floor division". It is the equivalent of int(floor(a/b)) without having to do any intermediate floating point math.

Answer (score 3):

If the number is already converted to an integer (i.e. base 10)

```
// Supports up to base 36
char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

char FindPlace(int number, int base, int digit)
{
   if(digit < 0) return 0;

   // Essentially divide the number by [base] to the [digit] power
   for(i=0; i<digit; i++)
   {
      number /= base;      
   }

   // TODO: Verify that the digit is in range of digits    
   return digits[number % base];
}
```

(`0` gives you the right most digit, `1` gives you the next to right-most digit, etc)

I've returned the digit as a `char`, to allow for bases more than 10.

Note that if you want to allow the user to input the desired digit as "`1`s place, `10`s place, `100`s place" or "`1`s, `16`s, `256`s", you simply do

```
digit = log(PlaceValue, base);
```

or rewrite the code to be

```
char FindPlace(int number, int base, int digitAsBaseToAPower)
{
    // TODO: Error checking
    return digits[(number / digitAsBaseToAPower) % base];
}
```

Comment: I should have specified that the number is passed numerically as opposed to a string notation.  I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

```
int getPlace(float x, float place) {

    return (int)(x/place) % 10;
}
```

This works for base-10, and can handle places to the right or left of the decimal.  You'd use it like this:

```
place = getPlace(1120,10);
otherPlace = getPlace(0.1120,1e-3);
```

A more general solution for any base is tricky.  I'd go with a string solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
int place_value(int value, int base, int place)
{
    int value_in_place= value;
    for (int place_index= 1; place_index<place; ++place_index)
    {
        value_in_place/=base;
    }

    return value_in_place % base;
}
```

where place is the one-based index of the digit you want from the right.

Comment: Are you sure it's a one-based index?  I think place_value(10, 10, 1) will return 1, not 0...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting the expected behavior using that.

Comment: Well, the fix is easy enough; simply say `for(int place_index=1;...)`

Comment: place_value(1120,10,1) returns 2.  I think you're off by a factor of base.

Comment: Err, I should have said zero-based index. Mea-culpa.

Comment: This is a good answer too.  I wish I could set more than one answer as the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The following method, *placeValue*, returns a **char**, because bases 11-36 have digits greater than 9.  The method expects:

- **int value:** the whole value
- **int base:** the number base to convert the whole to; acceptable values are 2-36
- **int place:** the index of the digit; the least significant digit has index 1

---

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

...

    private static char placeValue(int value, int base, int place) {
        BigInteger bigValue = BigInteger.valueOf(value);
        String baseString = bigValue.toString(base);
        int numDigits = baseString.length();
        int digitIndex = numDigits - place;
        char digit = baseString.charAt(digitIndex); 
        return digit;
    }
```